# database driven program in java, insert update delete in same jsp page

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp

I am developing in java. I have a form in jsp page which adds details in database (MySql).
I want to show all data in the jsp page below the form and it also should have facility to edit, delete, multiple selection in the table in jsp page. which method should i use to do so. please guide me....

Answer (score 2):

Well, as a guide I would tell you not to do all that in the same page.  Try to separe presentation duty from business logic, and that from the data layer, so you have smaller modules with defined tasks.  That way, when you have to change one thing, it will not affect the rest (and it is very common changing presentation and/or data layer at least once in an application life)